# Scala 3 implicit conversions: compare value and literal

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, scala-3

I have an opaque type `FancyDouble`, which is implicitly converted from Double by using `given Conversion[Double, FancyDouble] = FancyDouble(_)` in the companion object scope. After that, the construction `val d: FancyDouble = 0.0` works, but when I try to do the comparison like `if (d == 0.0)`, the compiler is complaining that I can't compare `FanceDouble` and `Double` (I am expecting that it should implicitly convert the `0.0` literal into FancyDouble, like in the previous case.

How can I enable the comparison with implicit conversions?

Comment: Can you show full definition of your opaque type and companion object? Also Conversion takes 2 type arguments

Comment: @texasbruce https://github.com/atemerev/cryptocore/blob/master/src/main/scala/ai/reactivity/cryptocore/Decimal.scala

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your error. See here https://scastie.scala-lang.org/erC4EXcuQUuHdmrAhgNBdA

Comment: Interesting! Thank you, I will investigate.

Comment: @texasbruce Indeed, it works like this (and if I define Decimal in the local scope), but it doesn't compile if Decimal is defined in a separate file in the same package. I don't understand...

Comment: Opaque types are "transparent" in the scope in which they are defined. Since it is defined in the top level of that scastie file, the entire script can see that `Decimal =:= Double`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Equality is essentially defined as `(Any, Any) => Boolean`. Mostly because of Java legacy. That means that in `fancyDouble == double` the expected type of expression `double` is `Any` and no implicit conversion will ever trigger.

However Scala 3 [introduced](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/contextual/multiversal-equality.html) the `CanEqual` typeclass to make equality a bit safer. If you want to compare values of type `A` and `B`, an implicit instance of `CanEqual[A, B]` needs to be in the implicit scope.

```scala
object fancy {
  opaque type FancyDouble = Double
  def make(d: Double): FancyDouble = d

  given CanEqual[FancyDouble, Double] = CanEqual.derived
  given CanEqual[Double, FancyDouble] = CanEqual.derived
}

val a = 4.2
val b = fancy.make(4.2)

assert(a == b) // ok
assert(b == a) // ok
```

If you enable the `strictEquality` flag, you even need a `CanEqual[FancyDouble, FancyDouble]` in order to compare two `FancyDouble`s.